# How to store session for Node.js Express with MongoDB in ReactJS + Redux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, reactjs

I am using Node.js Express with MongoDB in ReactJS and Redux, and I am new to MongoDB and finally got the database running. Users are able to register their credentials by making a POST request and the credentials would get stored in the database.

I now would like to implement a log in system where a user logs in and it would store the session, and fetch all the related information to the particular user that logged in.

What would be the recommended approach to doing so? A sample and a guidance would be extremely helpful. Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/session

Comment: @James111 is there an example with login?

Answer (score 0):

use Redis to store session. Refer this.

https://codeforgeek.com/2015/07/using-redis-to-handle-session-in-node-js/

Comment: I'm looking for something that would work with MongoDB